# React - hide component when an element in Navigation menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hide, router

is there a possibility to hide a react component when an element in navigation menu is clicked? I used React router to navigate to the corresponding components. I have a Navigation component, below is a Header component (which I want to hide/remove when I click on one of the options in Navigation), and then a div where the clicked content should be displayed. I'll be grateful for your suggestions. On the scr1 you can see how the app looks before the click on the Navigation item and on scr2 what happens. I want to hide the component with icons ().  Only Navigation and the  component should be visible.
Below you'll find necessary code and screenshots.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/style.css';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Menu from './components/Menu';
import Grammatica from './components/Grammatica'
import GrammaticaElement from './components/GrammaticaElement'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Lessico from './components/Lessico';
import Cultura from './components/Cultura';
import CompetenzeLinguistiche from './components/CompetenzeLinguistiche';
import Prove from './components/Prove';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
     <Navigation />
      <Header/>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/"/>
      <Route path="/grammatica" component={Grammatica}/>
      <Route path="/lessico" component={Lessico}/>
      <Route path="/cultura" component={Cultura}/>
      <Route path="/competenze-linguistiche" component={CompetenzeLinguistiche}/>
      <Route path="/prove" component={Prove}/>
      </Switch>
      
      {/*
      <Menu />
        */}
      
      
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Navigation.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import '../styles/style.css';
import {UncontrolledDropdown, Container, Row, Col, Nav, Navbar, NavItem, NavLink, Dropdown, DropdownItem, DropdownMenu, DropdownToggle} from 'reactstrap';
// import './fontawesomelibrary';
import { faHome, faInfo, faBars, faEdit, faPlus, faSpellCheck, faPizzaSlice, faLevelUpAlt, faTrophy, faIdCard } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import Grammatica from './Grammatica';
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom';
class Navigation extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.toggleGr = this.toggleGr.bind(this);
    this.toggleL = this.toggleL.bind(this);
    this.toggleC = this.toggleC.bind(this);
    this.toggleCL = this.toggleCL.bind(this);
    this.toggleP = this.toggleP.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        dropdownOpenGr:false,
        dropdownOpenL:false,
        dropdownOpenC:false,
        dropdownOpenCL:false,
        dropdownOpenP:false
    
    };
}

    toggleGr(){
        this.setState(prevState =>({
            dropdownOpenGr: !prevState.dropdownOpenGr
        }));
    }

    toggleL(){
        this.setState(prevState =>({
            dropdownOpenL: !prevState.dropdownOpenL
        }));
    }
    
    toggleC(){
        this.setState(prevState =>({
            dropdownOpenC: !prevState.dropdownOpenC
        }));
    }
    toggleCL(){
        this.setState(prevState =>({
            dropdownOpenCL: !prevState.dropdownOpenCL
        }));
    }
    toggleP(){
        this.setState(prevState =>({
            dropdownOpenP: !prevState.dropdownOpenP
        }));
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Container fluid="lg">
                    <Row>

                        <Nav className="nav-style">
                            <NavItem className="home"><NavLink href="#"><FontAwesomeIcon className="icon-style" icon={faBars}></FontAwesomeIcon></NavLink></NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                            <Link to="/" className="nav-bar-labels"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Home</Link></NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                            <NavLink className="nav-bar-labels" href="#"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfo} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Chi siamo</NavLink></NavItem>
                            <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpenGr} toggle={this.toggleGr}>
                            <NavItem>
                            <Link to="/grammatica" className="nav-bar-labels"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>
                            <DropdownToggle className="nav-bar-labels nav-bar-label-override">
                            Grammatica
                            </DropdownToggle>
                            </Link>
                            <DropdownMenu>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Spiegazioni</DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Prove</DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Esercizi</DropdownItem>
                            </DropdownMenu> 
                            </NavItem>
                            </Dropdown>
                            
                            <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpenL} toggle={this.toggleL}>
                            <NavItem>
                            <Link to="/lessico" className="nav-bar-labels" href="#"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSpellCheck} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>
                            <DropdownToggle className="nav-bar-labels nav-bar-label-override">Lessico</DropdownToggle>
                            </Link>
                            <DropdownMenu>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Situzaioni</DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Prove</DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Esercizi</DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Vocabolario illustrato</DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Modi di dire</DropdownItem>
                            </DropdownMenu> 
                            </NavItem>
                            </Dropdown>
                            
                            <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpenC} toggle={this.toggleC}>
                            <NavItem>
                            <Link to="/cultura" className="nav-bar-labels" href="#"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPizzaSlice} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>
                            <DropdownToggle className="nav-bar-labels nav-bar-label-override">Cultura</DropdownToggle>
                            </Link>
                            <DropdownMenu>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Civiltà italiana</DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>La cucina italiana</DropdownItem>
                            </DropdownMenu> 
                            </NavItem>
                            </Dropdown>
                            
                            <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpenCL} toggle={this.toggleCL}>
                            <NavItem>
                            <Link to="/competenze-linguistiche" className="nav-bar-labels" href="#"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLevelUpAlt} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>
                            <DropdownToggle className="nav-bar-labels nav-bar-label-override">Competenze linguistiche</DropdownToggle>
                            </Link>
                            <DropdownMenu>
                                <DropdownItem href="#" className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Prove di grammatica</DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem href="#" className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Compressione scritta</DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem href="#" className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Situazioni di communicazione</DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem href="#"className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Esercizi di riodinamento di testi</DropdownItem>
                            </DropdownMenu> 
                            </NavItem>
                            </Dropdown>

                            <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpenP} toggle={this.toggleP}>
                            <NavItem>
                            <Link to="/prove" className="nav-bar-labels" href="#"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrophy} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>
                            <DropdownToggle className="nav-bar-labels nav-bar-label-override">Prove</DropdownToggle>
                            </Link>
                            <DropdownMenu>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Prova il tuo italiano</DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem className="dropdown-item-style"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Quanto siete bravi in italiano?</DropdownItem>
                            </DropdownMenu> 
                            </NavItem>
                            </Dropdown>

                            <NavItem>
                            <NavLink className="nav-bar-labels" href="#"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faIdCard} className="icon-style"></FontAwesomeIcon>Contattaci</NavLink></NavItem>
                            <NavItem></NavItem>
                        </Nav>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `Header` component to the `/` path Route as it's component prop like so:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Header}/>
```

So that it will be shown only when you are on the home page (on `/` route).
The resulting `App.js` should like this-

```
<div className="App">
     <Navigation />
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Header}/>
      <Route path="/grammatica" component={Grammatica}/>
      <Route path="/lessico" component={Lessico}/>
      <Route path="/cultura" component={Cultura}/>
      <Route path="/competenze-linguistiche" component={CompetenzeLinguistiche}/>
      <Route path="/prove" component={Prove}/>
      </Switch>
      
      {/*
      <Menu />
        */}
      
      
</div>
```